# Regex - how to tell something NOT to match?

Tags: regex

How can I create a regex NOT to match something? For example I want to regex to match everything that is NOT the string "www.petroules.com".

I tried `[^www\.petroules\.com]` but that didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

```
^(?!www\.petroules\.com$).*$
```

will match any string other than `www.petroules.com`. This is called [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

```
[^www\.petroules\.com]
```

means "Match *one* character except w, p, e, t, r, o, u, l, s or dot".

Comment: Just what I needed, thanks. Will accept in ~10 minutes as you submitted the first correct answer.

Comment: `.*$` is a noop and can be omitted.

Comment: OK, but of course then the match result will be an empty string (with a successful match). If you're just checking whether a match is possible, then this doesn't matter. So yes, omit the `.*$`, and you're done faster.

Comment: good point.  I wasn't considering the match result.  So, `.*$` *might* be a noop, or might not, depending.

Comment: @Wayne, in this particular case the regex will only ever match the entire input string or nothing at all, so there is no real reason to actually match the string because you already know what the match is going to be. In other cases, of course, the actual match might matter.

Answer (score 28):

```
(?!...)
```

This is called negative lookahead. It will only match if the regex ... does not match. However, note that it DOES NOT consume characters. This means that if you add anything else past the ), it will start matching right away, even characters that were part of the negative lookahead.