# Problem with negative lookahead in R regex

Tags: r, regex

I have this kind of data :

```
MWE <- c(
  "World1    2.6       -4.5         1.5          5.0       -0.2",
  "1,2",
  "G20    112.9            -4.1                1.6                        5.7                    0.4"
)
```

The desired output is :

```
[1] "    2.6       -4.5         1.5          5.0       -0.2"                                                      
[2] ""                                                                                                               
[3] "   112.9                         -4.1                    1.6                        5.7                    0.4"
```

I want to separate what is a number and what is not (in this precise case, the `"1,2"` is a "mistake" in datamining and refers to footnotes for "G20", just to mention it is not a number I want to get).

I think the correct regex for the format is therefore `[-+]?\\d+\\.\\d`

And it works in the positive sense :

```
> MWE2 <- gsub("[-+]?\\d+\\.\\d","blah",MWE)  
> MWE2
[1] "World1    blah       blah         blah          blah       blah"                                                     
[2] "1,2"                                                                                                                 
[3] "G20    blah                         blah                    blah                        blah                    blah"
```

But when I try to isolate values by replacing every thing that is not that by nothing, with negative lookahead (I have understood from [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2967776/regex-how-to-tell-something-not-to-match) that it was what I was looking for) `(?! )`, so that : `(?![-+]?\\d+\\.\\d)`, but it does not seem to work (I have looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43458531/negative-lookahead-in-r-not-behaving-as-expected) and added the `perl=T` option)

```
> MWE3 <- gsub("(?![-+]?\\d+\\.\\d)","",MWE,perl=T)  
> MWE3
[1] "World1    2.6       -4.5         1.5          5.0       -0.2"                                                      
[2] "1,2"                                                                                                               
[3] "G20    112.9                         -4.1                    1.6                        5.7                    0.4"
```

Comment: There is no problem with the negative lookahead, it is working as expected. What is the expected output?

Comment: I added it, but will also look as it seems I have not understood sthg

Comment: Do you really want to keep the spacing? Try `sapply(regmatches(MWE, gregexpr("-?\\b\\d+\\.\\d\\b", MWE)), function(x) paste(x, collapse=" "))`

Comment: `^(?!www\.petroules\.com$).*$` matches any *full* string that is not equal to `www.petroules.com` - this is not your scenario.

Comment: I do not want to keep the spacing necessarily, I just need at least one space to be able to separate them later as a databaes

Comment: Then why not just extrac them? `regmatches(MWE, gregexpr("-?\\b\\d+\\.\\d\\b", MWE))` or `stringr::str_extract_all(MWE, "-?\\b\\d+\\.\\d\\b")`, see https://ideone.com/XeEvXi

Comment: Because I did not know it existed and used a more laborious approach :)